# Fans not working car keep running hot ac stop

Tags: pontiac, fan, g6

My Pontiac G6 2007 - It keeps getting hot. The fan is not cutting on the water keeps bobbling. It's making my AC stop working and now I'm hearing a sound like when your power steering is empty, but it not from my engine or something.

Comment: Have you checked the fan fuses and relays?

Answer (score 1):

start the car. wait till it gets warm and see if the fan flips on don't let it overheat. If it does your issue is in castle.

If it does not check the power lead to the fan and see if you get 12v out of it if so then fan is probably dead or has a bad ground lead.

next step is checking the fan temp sensor. It should be an open short when its cold and closed when hot. If it does not switch to a closed circuit when hot this should be replaced. Also make sure it is actually getting hot, no gunk built up on it or an air pocket due to low coolant or something.

If you do not get power then it may be a fan fuse or some relay or even a burnt up cut or damaged wire. You will need to pull out your shop manual and start tracing the wire back. Depending on how much you like the car you can simply bypass the whole thing with a new wire and fuse heck you could wire it right up to the dash and have a switch if you wanted to really cut everything out. I would only suggest doing these if it's not a replace dead part problem and ends up being a trace dead wire problem.

To help trace the wire if you do not have a shop manual is get a tone generator and a probe. As an IT guy these come in handy quite a bit and you can get them with alligator clips use it [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0HjaR0tj7Q)

.

for your battery issue pull the leads and see if there is a big short across them. If there is you get to do more wire tracing to isolate the short. This will cause a battery to go flat. Make sure you didn't leave an accessory on or a light or something first.

Comment: yes i did that now my car battery is going out after car cut off

Comment: edited my answer for the battery. how did the car cut off though?